# Стилизация некоторых слов внутри текста

Tags: java, android, textview

Делаю простой твитер клиент и столкнулся с проблемой.
В тексте твита есть упоминания про пользователя например: @user98 
как сделать что бы в тексте он выделялся и был кликабельным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать интерфейс Spannable. Он предназначен для стилизации текста. Например, так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавление маркировки осуществляется методом:

```
Spannable.setSpan(Object span, int start, int end, int flags);
```

Удаление, соответственно, методом:

```
Spannable.removeSpan(Object span);
```

Пример выделения текста:

```
// Create spannable text and set style.
Spannable text = new SpannableString("This is underline and bold text.");
text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 8, 17, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 22, 26, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Set spannable text in TextView.
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(text);
```

вот хорошая статья на эту тему на русском языке - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/spannable.php

Comment: Для кликабельности, соотвественно, ClickableSpan вместе с UnderlineSpan и/или с другими спанами.